# Sum of two rows

Tags: sql, sum, rows

Assuming I have a table like:

```
ID1 ID2 Country Value
1   2   GER     1000
1   2   USA     12
2   2   USA     13
3   2   MEX     16
```

Now I want SQL to merge the rows, where both the ID1 and ID2 are the same. Then, the sum of "Value" shall be calculated. The column "Country" shall remain and continue one of both names (does not matter which one).

So the final thing should be:

```
ID1 ID2 Country Value
1   2   GER     1012
2   2   USA     13
3   2   MEX     16
```

Any ideas? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just group by the two id columns, then use aggregation functions to calculate the other columns.

`SUM()` is easily the obvious aggregate for `value`

Then you can use `MIN()` or `MAX()` to make an arbitrary selection for `country`

```
SELECT
    id1,
    id2,
    MAX(country),
    SUM(value)
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    id1,
    id2
```